# C#でウィンドウメッセージ受信時にイベントを発生させたい

Tags: c#

お世話になります。  
　表題のとおりなんですが、C#でウィンドウメッセージを受信したときに、イベントを発生させたいと考えています。  
　とりあえず、ウィンドウメッセージを受信する処理とイベントクラスの作成はできたのですが、イベントを発生させる方法がよくわかりません。  
　下記のコードでは、コンパイルエラーが起きてしまうようです。  
　アドバイスを頂けないでしょうか。  
　よろしくお願いします。

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WndMessage{
    public class WndMessage{

        // メッセージ処理関数用デリゲート
        private delegate int D_MyWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        // ウィンドウをサブクラス化するAPI
        private static int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongA")]
        extern static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongA")]
        extern static int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongA")]
        extern static int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex, D_MyWndProc dwNewLong);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CallWindowProcA")]
        extern static int CallWindowProc(int lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        // デフォルトのメッセージ処理関数
        private static int lngWnP;

        // 独自メッセージの処理を開始
        public void StartReceiveMessage(IntPtr hwnd){
            lngWnP = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, MyWndProc);
        }

        // 独自メッセージの処理を終了
        public void ExitReceiveMessage(IntPtr hwnd){
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, lngWnP);
        }

        // ウィンドウに来たメッセージを振り分ける関数
        private static int MyWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam){
            return CallWindowProc(lngWnP, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }

        public class MessageEventArgs : EventArgs {
            private readonly int msg;
            private readonly int lParam;
            private readonly int wParam;

            public MessageEventArgs(int msg, int lParam, int wParam){
                this.msg = msg;
                this.lParam = lParam;
                this.wParam = wParam;
            }

            public int msg{
                get { return msg; }
            }

            public int lParam{
                get { return lParam; }
            }

            public int wParam{
                get { return wParam; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: サブクラス化する対象のウィンドウは何でしょうか？ 自身の持つ`WinForm`ですか？ それとも全く外部のプロセスですか？

Comment: コンパイルエラーがおきているなら、エラー内容も追記すると情報が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: ウィンドウ対象は、外部のウィンドウです。エラー内容ですが、「error CS0102: 型 'WndMessage.MessageEventArgs' は 'msg' の定義を既に含んでいます。」となっています。

Comment: 元々のソースも、[System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindowによる、ウインドウメッセージの横取り（サブクラス化）](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tekk/20091122/1258894786)を使うと簡略化できそうです。 NativeWindowを使ってC#のイベントを発生させる仕組みは、[WndProcをHookする](http://krdlab.hatenablog.com/entry/20070311/1173603961)のソースを、DrawClipboard, OnDrawClipboard をキーワードに追ってみてください。他には [C#のコンソールやライブラリでもメッセージによるプロセス間通信する(ウィンドウメッセージに寄り添うコンソールの作法2)](https://qiita.com/exliko/items/5764f971c98832dcfc8e), [クリップボードの内容をリアルタイムに取得するには？](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/dotnettips/848cbviewer/cbviewer.html), [C# グローバルフックでメッセージを編集して送り返す。](https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/1872) 等が参考になるでしょう。

Comment: うーん、かなり難しいですね。もうちょっと頑張ってみますが。

Answer (score 1):

> error CS0102: 型 'WndMessage.MessageEventArgs' は 'msg' の定義を既に含んでいます。

`private readonly int msg;` フィールドと `public int msg{ get { return msg; } }` プロパティとで名前が重複しています。フィールド、プロパティ、メソッド等で同名の識別子を使用することはできません。

---

> ```
> private static int lngWnP;
> ```

ここに限らず、ウィンドウプロシージャを`int`で保持していますが64bit環境で破綻します。`IntPtr`を使用するとともに`Get/SetWindowLongPtr`も検討してください。